# Vue доавить в запрос переменную

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как в запрос api/v2/image еще добавить id ? к примеру некая переменная id = 1

```
<input type="file" ref="avatar" @change="upload">

         upload(event){
                let data = new FormData();
                let file = event.target.files[0];

                data.append('file', file)

                let config = {
                  header : {
                     'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
                 }
             }
             axios.post('api/v2/image', data, config)
         },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно добавить пару ключ/значение в FormData:

```
FormData.append(name, value);
```

Более подробно здесь:
https://devdocs.io/dom/formdata/append

Comment: подскажите в моем случае как оптимизировать код чтоб работало ?

Comment: просто добавьте строчку
data.append(name, value); подставив вместо name и value ключ и значение, которое вы хотите